# Dialog box is not opening on click of notification

Tags: android, dialog, notifications

I am trying to open dialog on click of notification but unable to do this:

Here's my code:

```
Intent in = new Intent(context, SnoozeEvent.class);
    in.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
    PendingIntent Sender = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(context, 0, intent, 0);
    manager = (NotificationManager)context.getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
    notification = new Notification(R.drawable.icon, "Wake up alarm", System.currentTimeMillis());
    notification.setLatestEventInfo(context, "Hanuman Chalisa", "Wake Up...", Sender);
    manager.notify(1, notification);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error is that you point the PendingIntent to an intent that doesn't exist (it points to an intent called "intent" - you created an intent called "in").

Replace the following line:

```
PendingIntent Sender = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(context, 0, intent, 0);
```

With this (so it points to the intent you created):

```
PendingIntent Sender = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(context, 0, in, 0);
```

If you do that, then everything should work fine.